# Unique combinations of two variables in R (dplyr::distinct not working)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, combinations, tidyverse

I'm looking to filter unique combinations of character strings from two columns of a dataframe.

Initial dataframe:

```
trial<-data.frame(x=c("A","B"),y=c("B","A"))
trial
  x y
1 A B
2 B A
```

The desired result :

```
  x y
1 A B
```

So far Ive tried using `dplyr::distinct() version 0.8.3` and `unique(trial[,c("x","y"])` but neither has generated the desired result. Adding more characters to each column to have manually created combinations does not help out.

```
        trial %>% 
      distinct(x,y)
      x y
    1 A B
    2 B A

    unique(trial[,c("x","y")])
      x y
    1 A B
    2 B A
```

Is there something I'm missing in order for these to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can reorder the values in the rows and then use `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
trial %>% 
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  transmute(x1 = pmin(x, y), y1 = pmax(x, y)) %>%
  rename_all(~ names(trial)) %>%
  distinct
 #  x y
 #1 A B
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
unique(t(apply(trial, 1, sort)))
#    [,1] [,2]
#[1,] "A"  "B"
```